# Keep Columns When Aggregating an Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm working in pandas 0.18.0 on python 2.7.9.

Take a sample `DataFrame` and group by a few columns, then sum over a different column for the result, like this:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> print df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  1  2  9
>>> df.groupby(['a','b'], as_index=False)['c'].sum()
   a  b   c
0  1  2  12
1  4  5   6
```

That all looks great, but when the same operation is preformed on an empty `DataFrame` the columns are dropped from the result:

```
>>> empty = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
>>> print empty
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
>>> empty.groupby(['a','b'], as_index=False)['c'].sum() 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Were someone to reference valid columns from the result later in the code, a key error would result. Is there a way to keep the columns?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a standard result of groupby.sum() (see here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

The only way I can think would be to write an if statement checking if the dataframe is empty, e.g.:

```
if sum(empty.isnull().sum()) == 9:
    print "empty dataframe"
elif sum(empty.isnull().sum()) < 9:
    empty.groupby(['a','b'], as_index=False)['c'].sum()
```

This should keep your empty dataframe with column headers.
Hope this helps.